# assign a string to a structure variable in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, compiler-construction, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct t_name
{
     char last_name[25];
     char first_name[15];
     char middle_init[2];
} NAME;
NAME my_name, your_name;
int main()
{
    char temp[] = "sumit";
    printf("Program started\n");
    my_name.first_name=temp;
    your_name = my_name;
    NAME abc=my_name;
    printf("my_name=%s\n",my_name.first_name);
    printf("your_name=%s\n",your_name.first_name);
    printf("abc=%s\n",abc.first_name);
}
```

But error occurs in following statement `my_name.first_name=temp;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[15]’ from type ‘char *’

```
define variable char *first_name
```

instead of

```
char first_name[15];
```

Try this

```
typedef struct t_name{

char *first_name;
char *middle_init;
char *last_name;
}NAME;
NAME my_name,your_name;

int main()
{
char temp[] = "sumit";
printf("Program started\n");
my_name.first_name=temp; // now you can assign value
your_name = my_name;
NAME abc=my_name;
printf("my_name=%s\n",my_name.first_name);
printf("your_name=%s\n",your_name.first_name);
printf("abc=%s\n",abc.first_name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The erros is (something that you should have posted):

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[15]’ from type ‘char *’
```

You cannot copy strings like that, you need to copy character by character or use library function `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 2):

In C you cannot use `=` to assign strings.
You should use `strcpy()`, like in this example:

```
/* strcpy example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str1[]="Sample string";
  char str2[40];
  char str3[40];
  strcpy (str2,str1);
  strcpy (str3,"copy successful");
  printf ("str1: %s\nstr2: %s\nstr3: %s\n",str1,str2,str3);
  return 0;
}
```

from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/